# MongoDB: Find documents with key in subdocument

Tags: mongodb

The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator works with arrays.

Is there an equivalent for dictionaries?

The following code creates two test documents and finds the ones containing one of the listed values in the array documents, but doesn't find the ones containing the same values in the sub-documents.

```
> use test
> db.stuff.drop()
> db.stuff.insertMany([{lst:['a','b'],dic:{a:1,b:2}},{lst:['a','c'],dic:{a:3,c:4}}])
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedIds" : [
                ObjectId("595bbe8b3b0518bcca4b1530"),
                ObjectId("595bbe8b3b0518bcca4b1531")
        ]
}
> db.stuff.find({lst:{$in:['b','c']}},{_id:0})
{ "lst" : [ "a", "b" ], "dic" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } }
{ "lst" : [ "a", "c" ], "dic" : { "a" : 3, "c" : 4 } }
> db.stuff.find({dic:{$in:['b','c']}},{_id:0})
>
```

**EDIT** (in response to the answer below)

Using the list as suggested in the answer below prevents me from finding the desired element. For example, after executing both the `insertMany` above in this question and below in the answer, the following can be done with a dictionary, not with a list (or am I missing something?):

```
> x=db.stuff.findOne({lst:{$in:['b','c']}},{_id:0})
{ "lst" : [ "a", "b" ], "dic" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } }
> x
{ "lst" : [ "a", "b" ], "dic" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } }
> x.dic.a
1
> x.dic.b
2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For subdocuments, there's no exact equivalent to $in. You could use the $exists query operator combined with $or:

```
db.stuff.find({$or:[
    {'dic.b': {$exists: true}},
    {'dic.c': {$exists: true}}
]})
```

The recommended approach, however, is to change your schema, so that the keys and values are changed into an array of `{key: "key", value: 123}` subdocuments:

```
db.stuff.insertMany([
   {dic: [{key: 'a', value: 1}, {key: 'b', value: 2}]},
   {dic: [{key: 'a', value: 3}, {key: 'c', value: 4}]}
])
```

Then you can use $in to find documents with certain keys:

```
db.stuff.find({'dic.key': {$in: ['a', 'b']}})
```

The especially good thing about this new schema is you can use an index for the $in query:

```
db.stuff.createIndex({'dic.key': 1})
```

A disadvantage, as you point out above, is that simple element access like `x.dic.a` no longer works. You need to do a bit of coding in your language. E.g. in Javascript:

```
> var doc = {dic: [{key: 'a', value: 3}, {key: 'c', value: 4}]}
> function getValue(doc, key) {
...   return doc.dic.filter(function(elem) {
...     return elem.key == key;
...   })[0].value;
... }
> getValue(doc, "a")
3
> getValue(doc, "c")
4
```

Comment: I had a comment too long to write here, so I edited the question. Can you please have a look at it and let me know your opinion?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will decide case by case, perhaps depending on the size of the list/dictionary, what strategy to use.

Comment: This might be the best answer to any question on StackOverflow.